# Vue Js v-model on v-select show wrong value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have somekind of bug on my v-select which cause the v-model to show different value than the real value of the variable. I use a method to change the selected option which work for the first change. Example if i chose False and flag = Y then the selected option will change to True, this work the for the first time you chose the option then when i change the value from True to False it will change the value but the selected option is still on False.

```html
<v-col cols="9">
      <v-select
           v-model="promo_form.generate_voucher"
           @input="methodUsed"
           :rules="textInputRules"
           :items="['False', 'True']"
           required
           outlined
      ></v-select>
</v-col>
```

Here is the method i use:

```js
if(this.flag_member == 'N' && this.promo_form.generate_voucher == 'True'){
     this.promo_form.promo_id = null;
     this.flag_member = "";
     this.promo_form.generate_voucher = null;
     this.promo_form.voucher_type = "";
     this.flag1 = 'y';
}
else if(this.flag_member == 'Y' && this.promo_form.generate_voucher == "False"){
     this.promo_form.generate_voucher = "True";
     this.flag1 = 'n'
}

if(this.flag1 == 'y'){
     alert('Something')
}
else if(this.flag1 == 'n'){
     alert("Something")
}
```

I tried adding label and the value is true for the label but not for the v-model

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in method try to change this line

```
this.promo_form.generate_voucher = null
```

to

```
this.promo_form.generate_voucher = 'False'
```